# how to delete blank line which is inserted by vscode auto-formating function?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir

My `elixir` code is as follows, the editor is vscode. When auto formating by shortcut key of alt-shift-f, a blank line will appear before the following `Logger.debug` line. It will reappear even if it is  deleted. Why it need a blank line here. Is it possible to not add the blank line?

```
  test "calculate_line_point_test 1/4,1 point" do
    whole_angle = :math.pi() / 4
    start_angle = :math.atan(1 / 4)
    n = 4
    k = 1
    result = InventoryMap.calculate_line_point(whole_angle, start_angle, n, k, 3, [])
    # {2,10}
    assert result == [
             {2, 0.21866894587394198},
             {3, 0.17985349979247828},
             # [{2, 0.21866894587394198}]
             {4, 0.1418970546041638}
           ]
             #<---- blank line appear here
    Logger.debug("get_angle: #{inspect(result)}")
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour has nothing to do with a particular editor, they all delegate to the language server *and* [`mix format`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Format.html) which is exposed by [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) itself (dig around [`Code.Fragment`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.Fragment.html).)

Formatter is the tool provided by [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) core team to standardize the code L&F. While it’s still possible to implement custom formatters and plug them into the existing project, I would strongly discourage doing that.

`mix format` is the standard member of the CI pipeline and everyone expects it to perform in a common way (e. g. as after the standard `mix format` without any custom formatters applied.) Just accept it :)